# Android Studio 3.0 Supporting Kotlin : Activity as Context

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Since the release of Android Studio 3.0 Canary, I've been trying to learn Kotlin and there is something I cannot understand. 
I was trying to make a simple Activity with a Button and a TextView. 
I cannot understand why Android Studio cannot recognize the activity as a Context.
In my code I try to make a Toast, but AS gives me in error when i put **this** as the context in the parameter.

The error is : "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied". And highlight **Context** in red

Here's the code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    fun AppCompatActivity.toast(message: CharSequence) = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button = findViewById(R.id.mainButton) as Button
        button.setOnClickListener{
            this@MainActivity.toast("proof")
            Log.e("asd","proof")
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is that when I run the code I get no flaws, no runtime exception. It's just Android Studio that doesn't recognize this as the context

Comment: Looks like a bug in AS/the Kotlin plugin to me. It's a canary build of Android Studio 3.0 after all, so don't worry about it for now.

Comment: I'm also getting this issue while not using Kotlin (just straight Java)

Comment: btw, there are beautiful Anko libraries that help you with many such cases - e.g. "toast" is there straight out of the box - https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android Studio 3.0 f you use `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1`, `AppCompatActivity` is not ***recognised*** as a "Context Object."

The `AppCompatActivity` class extends a `FragmentActivity` which, in turn, extends `BaseFragmentActivityJB`

Because Android Studio 3.0 can not find that class, it won't accept AppCompatActivity as the Context.

Updating `appcompat-v7` to 25.3.1 or newer should fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The error happens because you have declared `toast` as an extension method on `AppCompatActivity` (because you've put `AppCompatActivity.` before its name), and also as a method (because it's declared inside your class). Everything should start working if you move the `toast` method declaration outside the `MainActivity` class. You can also remove `this@MainActivity` from your code; it's redundant.